# Calling Facebook Workplace API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-workplace

I am playing around with Facebook's Workplace API. I have some experience working with Facebook's Graph API using the Graph API explorer, but I don't know how to call the API for workplace in the Graph API explorer. Or is there a separate Graph API explorer tool for Workplace?

### Update 1

I have created the Workplace account using my domain email, but my Facebook account was created on my personal Gmail account. The Graph API explorer is opened in my personal Facebook account. Could this also be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I am doing it. I am not using the Graph API explorer, but I am using postman.

Suppose you want to get the list of grp from the workplace.

With a GET req, enter the URL `https://graph.facebook.com/community`, and in the `Headers` section, add `Authorization Bearer <access token>`, press send, and you will see list of grps.

This is how I am doing it now.

Comment: This did not work for me @Raaz. I used the graph api  explorer to access the same